# Create a row for each record separated by some pattern

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split, exploded

I need to create a row in the pandas dataframe for each record in the `"ativos"` column and the other data (`"nome"`) must be repeated. Records are separated by this string `"\r\n"` in the `"ativos"` column. However, I don't know how to do it correctly.

```
   nome            activos
0  Luiz  ABC\r\nDEF\r\nGHI
```

Expected result:

```
   nome activos
0  Luiz     ABC
1  Luiz     DEF
2  Luiz     GHI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.split` and `explode`:

```
out = df.assign(activos=df['ativos'].str.split(r'\\r\\n')).explode('ativos')
print(out)

# Output
   nome ativos
0  Luiz    ABC
0  Luiz    DEF
0  Luiz    GHI
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nome': ['Luiz'], 'ativos': [r'ABC\r\nDEF\r\nGHI']})
print(df)

# Output
   nome             ativos
0  Luiz  ABC\r\nDEF\r\nGHI
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` and `explode`:

```
df['activos'] = df['activos'].str.split(r'\\r\\n')
df.explode('activos', ignore_index=True)
```